# CONCATENATE cells in a column IF condition in other colum is met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

Using Google sheets (or Excel if Google sheets can't do it). I'm trying to concatenate any cell in B column, if its corresponding A cell is "include". The columns are very long and therefore I don't want to do a long list of IF statements.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| include | red |
| exclude | blue |
| include | green |
| exclude | yellow |

In this example, the results should be: **redgreen**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel 2019/365 you can do:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,IF(A1:A4="include",B1:B4,""))
```

In Google Sheets:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN("",true,IF(A1:A4="include",B1:B4,"")))
```

For Excel 2010 (I think):

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(INDEX(B1:B4,(2*(A1:A4="include")-1)*ROW(A1:A4),1),""))
```

entered with CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER because it is an array formula. If your data are not starting in A1, then you need to modify this more:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR( INDEX(B1:B4,(2*(A1:A4="include")-1)*(ROW(A1:A4)-ROW(A1)+1),1),""))
```

Change the ranges to where A1:A4 and B1:B4 really are and set ROW(A1) to the first row of the data.

> NB: replace formula comma separators with semi-colons (;) depending on
> Excel installed language.

Comment: Great stuff! I particularly appreciate learning about textjoin, much more elegant than concatenate in this case.